# mix-blend-mode с фоном на body

Tags: css, google-chrome

Почему наличие строк

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

влияет на поведение `mix-blend-mode`? Без них он не работает, а с ними нормально:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
}

div {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
}

div {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
```

Comment: В Firefox оба сниппета отображаются полностью одинаково. Баг хрома?

Comment: Если изменить height или margin так, чтобы пропала полоса прокрутки, возникающая во втором сниппете — то тоже сломается. По-моему всё-таки баг

Comment: Ну и если прописать `overflow:hidden` с любыми height и margin, то тоже сломается

Comment: @andreymal, какой-то странный баг... Ответ напишешь?)

Comment: а с градиентом в body без height:100% проблемы нет? периодически попадались случаи когда фон лишь часть страницы покрывает. особенно когда элементов на странице мало(меньше одного экрана). // на FF

Comment: @puffleeck, position не используется, значит body растягивается чтобы вместить весь контент. Можешь outline добавить и проверить.

Comment: @puffleeck, вообще, с градиентом проблемы могли бы быть, если бы он был в другую сторону, но конкретно в mix-blend-mode они не относятся.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну это по стандарту растягивается, а мы ведь баг ищим, не?) p.s. у меня только FF, хрома нету, так что всё что подсказываю, проверять вам придется самостоятельно... сэ ля ви.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ах да, пока помню... старый хромиум таки есть, и тот напрочь отказывался воспринимать направление градиента словами. т.е. "90deg" работает а "to right" нет. попробуйте поменять, может отголоски этого бага дают о себе знать. других идей пока нету.

Comment: @puffleeck, даже с однотонным фоном не работает ;)